# Translating pycountry subdivisions to english

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a project where I get a user provided countries' province/state data in English. 
And when I have to store it in the database, I need the iso 3166-2 code of the province.

The problem is, I am using pycountry and pycountry has the province information only in the local language (German for Germany).
For eg: Lower Saxony in german is Niedersachsen.

Because of this, I cannot look up the code using the English name, which I get from the data source.

I have tried the below:

```
>>>gettext.translation('iso3166-2', pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, languages=['en']).install()   
>>> country_code = ''.join([subdivision.code for subdivision in pycountry.subdivisions if _(subdivision.name) == 'Lower Saxony'])  
>>> country_code # prints ' '
```

I have also tried to use the googletran to do a literal german to english translation which does not work for all cases.

```
>>>import googletrans
>>> translator = Translator()
>>> s = translator.translate('Rheinland-Pfalz', src='de', dest='en')
>>> s.text
u'Rheinland-Pfalz'
>>> s = translator.translate('Rheinland Pfalz', src='de', dest='en')
>>> s.text
u'Rheinland Pfalz'
>>> s = translator.translate('rheinland-Pfalz', src='de', dest='en')
>>> s.text
u'Rhineland-Palatinate'
>>> s = translator.translate('rheinland-pfalz', src='de', dest='en')
>>> s.text
u'rhineland'
>>> s = translator.translate('rheinland-pfalz', src='de', dest='en')  
>>> s.text   
u'rhineland'
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!